# Как запретить gradle ходить в интернет за обновлениями?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

можно ли запретить gradle обновляться из интернета?

Answer (score 3):

В настройках Android Studio можно включить gradle offline mode

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build tools > Gradle

Comment: включил режим `gradle offile mode`, появилась ошибка `> A problem occurred starting proocess 'command '/home/android/android-sdk-update-manager/build-tools/24.0.0-preview/aapt''`, приложение обычный `Hello world`, что ему не нравится?

Comment: Перед сборкой надо попробовать сделать clean проекта

Answer (score 0):

Очистить то, что внутри блока repositories и использовать только AAR/JAR файлы:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    }
}


compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```